# Interface in generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics, types, interface, implements

I need to parameterise my class by Enum with some concrete methods, something like:

```
class K<E extends Enum<E> implements SomeInterface>
```

But Eclipse prohibit me to use "implements" word in "<>". What can I do to solve my problem? Is there any sensible reason why can't I use "implements" in definition of generic type?

Answer (score 11):

Generic constraints use the word `extends` for both base classes and interfaces.

To constrain on multiple types, use an `&`:

```
class K<E extends Enum<E> & SomeInterface>
```

Comment: woww..this is the first time that I am seeing `&` withing generic type definition.!!! Can you please tell me the links where I can get to know more about such things?

Comment: @Mac: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4

Answer (score 2):

You would use `extends` in this case:

```
class K<E extends Enum<E>&SomeInterface>
```

Please note that if it needs to also extend a class it **must** come before any interfaces.

Comment: You can't extend more than one class in Java

Comment: @Jeffrey Sorry, getting languages mixed up. One class extended, comes first.